# Rollback strategy on mule not working

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, mule, rollback

From Mule, I am trying to build a flow to read the messages from active MQ and send it to DB. So within my flow, I have a JMS inbound endpoint,followed by Java component, where I am making JDBC connections.Now my problem is , I want to implement a rollback which will try to rollback messages to Q if there is any connection problem on the backend. 
This does seems to be working, but partially. So when there is an exception on the java component, I see messages are rolling back. But even after reaching maximum redelivery attempts, I do not see the block under   section getting executed.
What type of transaction should I be using in this case.?

Please suggest how to fix this issue.

`

```
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="TestQ"
        connector-ref="ActiveMQ" doc:name="JMS" >
          <ee:multi-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"></ee:multi-transaction>  
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>

    <component class="com.test.JDBCComponent" doc:name="Java"/>

    <rollback-exception-strategy
        maxRedeliveryAttempts="3" doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy">

        <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded
            doc:name="Redelivery exhausted">
            <logger message="EXHAUSTER REDILVERY" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
        </on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
    </rollback-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

`

Comment: What is the configuration of your jms connector?

Comment: Did your com.test.JDBCComponent component join the begun transaction af JMS inbound?

Answer (score 0):

It should work aditya , as if this is not working you can use untill - successful scope.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/until-successful-scope

Answer (score 0):

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ"
brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" maxRedelivery="5" />
```

maxRedelivery attribute in the connector definition goes in conflict with maxRedeliveryAttempts of the roll-back strategy

The smallest wins..

As per the transaction looks correctly configured.